# .NET MVC - Ajax POST not calling .Net MVC method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to .NET MVC. I'm trying to make an Ajax call to a .NET method, but it doesn't work. Please help.

Here is my Ajax code:

```
function resendConfirmationEmail()
{
    $("#resend-confirmation-email-status").html('<img src="../../Content/img/ajax-loader.gif" />');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Ultility/ResendConfirmationEmail",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "userID": $('#confirmation-email-userid').text().toString(), "subject": $('#confirmation-email-subject').text().toString() }),
        async: true,
        processData: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#resend-confirmation-email-status").html("Email sent");
        }
    });
}
```

And here is my .Net method in UtilityController:

```
[HttpPost]
[WebMethod]
public JsonResult ResendConfirmationEmail(string userID, string subject)
{
    string destination = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userID).Select(u => u.Email).FirstOrDefault();
    Task<string> result = new AccountController().SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userID, subject, destination);
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work'?.  Have you checked your browsers console log to see what's going on?

Comment: Yes, I have already checked the Ajax function in the browser, it worked. But it wouldn't call the .NET method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the quotation marks in the data parameters of the ajax request

Like this:

```
function resendConfirmationEmail()
{
    $("#resend-confirmation-email-status").html('<img src="../../Content/img/ajax-loader.gif" />');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Ultility/ResendConfirmationEmail",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: 
             JSON.stringify({ 
               userID: $('#confirmation-email-userid').text().toString(),
               subject: $('#confirmation-email-subject').text().toString() 
             }),
        async: true,
        processData: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#resend-confirmation-email-status").html("Email sent");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, but if you using asp.net mvc, i guess you don't need [WebMethod] attribute

```
    [HttpPost]
    [WebMethod]
public JsonResult ResendConfirmationEmail([FromBody] MyModel model)
{
  ....
}

public class MyModel{
   public string userID {get; set;}
   public string string subject {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think issue with your url where in 
use "url: "/Ultility/ResendConfirmationEmail","
insted of "url: "/Utility/ResendConfirmationEmail","

because your controller name is UtilityController

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use Webmethod in .net method
2. No need to use JSON.Stringify in ajax

```
    function resendConfirmationEmail()
        {
            $("#resend-confirmation-email-status").html('<img src="../../Content/img/ajax-loader.gif" />');
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Ultility/ResendConfirmationEmail",
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               data: "{'userID': "+$('#confirmation-email-userid').text().toString()+",'subject': "+$('#confirmation-email-subject').text().toString()+" }",
                async: true,
                processData: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#resend-confirmation-email-status").html("Email sent");
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the [webmothod] data annotation from your action method,
2. second option you are trying to pass json object for that u dont need to convert into string. Simply pass object

It wil work